# finish() won't take back from Activity2 to Activity1

Tags: android, onactivityresult, activity-finish

I have an app built of two Activities.
the main activity (activity 1), using some button, takes you to activity 2 using a `startActivityforResult`.

Activity 2 is a file chooser that chooses some file by clicking on it.
once the file is chosen, I want it to send the data (the chosen file path), as a string, back to activity 1 and return to Activity 1. So that Activity 1 will do something with the file (as written in Activity 1's `onActivityResult`).

I am using a simple `onListItemClick` implementation (the file chooser uses a list view to show the list from which we choose the file).

And in the case where the choice is indeed a file (verified by a "Toast" output to the user).

**There is a finish() method that's supposed to send back the data and take you back to Activity 1.**

Here's the code for Activity 2's `onListItemClick` method. if more is needed, tell me and I'll add the rest of the activity):

```
@Override
protected void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) 
{
String filename = (String) getListAdapter().getItem(position);
if (path.endsWith(File.separator)) 
{
filename = path + filename;System.out.println("Ends with file separator\n");
} 
else 
{
        filename = path + File.separator + filename;System.out.println("No file separator\n");
}
if (new File(filename).isDirectory()) 
{
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, ListFileActivity.class);
        intent.putExtra("path", filename);
        startActivity(intent);//re-do this activity, to enter the directory
 } 
else 
{
        File F=new File(filename);
        Toast.makeText(this, filename + " is not a directory, file chosen!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        String P=F.getAbsolutePath();
        System.out.printf("---------------Absolute directory is %s\n",P);
        Intent ResultIntent=new Intent();
        ResultIntent.putExtra("Address",filename);
        setResult(Activity.RESULT_OK,ResultIntent);
        finish();
}
}
```

Thanks everyone for your kind help,
Julius

Comment: "but it doesn't do that"....what **does** it do? Also, are you calling `finish()` in `Activity1` after `startActvitiyForResult()`?

Comment: you are stacking activities by using `startActivity(intent);` over and over again.

Comment: When you launch `Activity2` from `Activity2` add `FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP` and implement `onNewIntent`. You don't want to start multiple `Activity2`s, you have to handle all directory navigation in this one instance. Then when you call `finish` it will take the result back to `Activity1`.

Comment: You're right, Eugen! I switched to using the SingleTop mode and now it works! but shouldn't I use the FLAG_SINGLE_TOP when I call Activity2 on the first time also (when called from activity1)? (when called from activity 1). what's the difference?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that you have posted the `Activity1` code,  when you do `finish()` it is finishing the `Activity1` not the `Activity2`

Comment: @Julius on what class this onListItemClick  is written?

Comment: The Activity poated is Activity 2.